# Another way to get text of Alerts in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I know that we can get the message of an alert this way.

- navigate to the frame:

  ```
  driver.switchto().alert()
  ```
- get the text :

  ```
  alert.gettext()
  ```

But is there any other way?

Comment: Why? Is there a problem with the way you mentioned?

Comment: No Sir, i was asked to do in a different way and the above one they dont want it..hence asked it. Thanks